# Is it possible to access value in a list in Revel Template

Tags: go, templates, revel

```
{{ range .foo }}
                
{{end}}
```

.

```
{{range $index, $element := .foo }}

{{end}}
```

I'm aware that you can use this like for loop, but is there any other way to access a value in array directly like `{{ foo[2] }}` in Revel Template?
I've read [this](https://revel.github.io/manual/templates-go.html) Revel documentation but doesn't seem to find any.

Comment: You can use the function `index`: *"Returns the result of indexing its first argument by the following arguments. Thus "index x 1 2 3" is, in Go syntax, x[1][2][3]. Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not Revel specific, indexing is included in the standard library templates:

```
{{index .foo 2}}
```